# Recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Sequence $a_n$ is defined $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-2, a_0=\alpha$.

I know that a closed form for $a_n$ is $a_n=\beta^{2^n}+\frac{1}{\beta^{2^n}}$, where $\beta$ satisfies $\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}=\alpha$ and I can prove it by induction.

But this way, we have to know answer. Is there any other solution that leads us to this form?

Comment: By "answer" you mean closed form?

Comment: @ZainPatel yes.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Use the double angle formula for cosine to show that if $a_n=2\cos\theta$, then $a_{n+1}=2\cos(2\theta)$.

Comment: Although depending on the size of $|\alpha|$, we might need imaginary $\theta$ or equivalently hyperbolic cosines.

Comment: There really is no one solution in real variables for all real conditions.  The behavior for initial values outside $[-2,2]$ versus inside that interval are too far apart for real-variable functions to cope.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, there is no general method for solving non-linear difference equations, even quadratic ones like this.  The equation may suggest the clever transformation $$
\begin{align}
a_n&=b_n+\frac1{b_n}\\
a_n^2&=b_n^2+\frac1{b_n^2}+2\\
a_{n+1}&=b_n^2+\frac1{b_n^2}\\
b_{n+1}&=b_n^2
\end{align}$$
but I don't know that I'd have come up with that if I hadn't seen the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is very close to a rival relation $a_{n+1}=a_n^2$ with easy solution $a_n=\alpha^{2^n}$, it's natural to try $a_n=\beta^{2^n}+\epsilon_n$ for some $\beta$ and sequence $\epsilon_n$ of small error terms. So$$\beta^{2^{n+1}}+\epsilon_{n+1}=(\beta^{2^n}+\epsilon_n)^2-2\implies\epsilon_{n+1}=2\beta^{2^n}\epsilon_n+\epsilon_n^2-2.$$This would be easy to solve if we only kept one of the last three terms, so let's try to cancel two of them. There are only so many combinations to try. You quickly realize cancelling the first and third gives the consistent conditions $\epsilon_n=\beta^{-2^n}$ and $\epsilon_{n+1}=\epsilon_n^2$. Then$$a_n=\beta^{2^n}+\beta^{-2^n}\implies\alpha=\beta+\beta^{-1}.$$